# How to connect to foxpro db using XbaseJ

Tags: foxpro, xbase

I want to fetch data from fox pro data base and insert it into Mysql. For that purpose i am using **XbaseJ**. But how can i connect to my **FoxPro** data base using **XbaseJ**.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [xBaseJ sample code](http://xbasej.sourceforge.net/example2.html)?

```
/**  
**/ package org.xBaseJ.examples;

/**
 * @author joseph mcverry
 *
 */
import org.xBaseJ.*;
import org.xBaseJ.fields.CharField;
import org.xBaseJ.fields.LogicalField;
import org.xBaseJ.fields.NumField;

public class example2 {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        String dow[] = {"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};


        try{
            //Open dbf file
            DBF classDB=new DBF("class.dbf");

            //Define fields
            CharField classId  = (CharField) classDB.getField("classId");
            CharField name  = (CharField) classDB.getField("className");
            CharField teacher = (CharField) classDB.getField("teacherId");
            CharField daysMeet  = (CharField) classDB.getField("daysMeet");
            CharField time = (CharField) classDB.getField("timeMeet");
            NumField credits = (NumField) classDB.getField("credits");
            LogicalField underGrad  = (LogicalField) classDB.getField("UnderGrad");

            for (int i = 1; i <= classDB.getRecordCount(); i++)
            {
                classDB.read();
                if (underGrad.getBoolean()) // just show undergrad courses
                {
                    System.out.println(name.get() + " id " + classId.get());
                    System.out.print("   Meets at: " + time.get() + " on ");
                    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
                    {
                        if (daysMeet.get().charAt(j) == 'Y')
                            System.out.print(dow[j] + " ");
                    }
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println("   Credits: " + credits.get());
                } // end if undergrad test
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The above example is based on the table that is created by the user within this XbaseJ code. In my case i will use the db that is already being created. I just want to configure that db with this class and then i will fetch the data as required.